# Dialog Button First Use for Android App

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button, dialog

i have configured a dialog to be show at the first time use of android app , and this dialog contain button , how to hide this dialog once i submit the button
here is my code

MainActivity code

```
 private boolean isFirstTime() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {
        //show dialog if app never launch
        dialog.show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.commit();

    }
    return !ranBefore;
}

//Create Dialog
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_user);
    //method call
```

user_dialog layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="453dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/first_login" />

</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnok"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:text="OK, GOT IT"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

[once click on OK,GOT IT to be dimess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YXNd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you have to do the findViewById on the dialog because the button is in the dialog.

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_user);
    Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnok);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

However the dialog could be deteled in other ways like clicking outside it or clicking the back arrow. If you want to delete your dialog only with your button, then you have to add: `dialog.setCancelable(false);`

Comment: where to add it , i call the dialog inside MainActivity , while i have implement the dialog inside another xml